# passing a 2D array name as an argument to function in awk

Tags: awk

I want to pass a 2D array as an argument to the function in awk . I tried this

```
add(element1,element2,array) -> this "array" could be bigArray,smallArray etc

function add(element1,element2,array)
{
      if(!(element1 SUBSEP element2 in array))
      {
            array[element1,element2]
      }

}
```

The array in the add function keeps on changing . But I am getting an error stating that "attempt to use scalar parameter array as an array". But the same thing when I pass a 1D array it works. Could you ppl please help me regarding this

Comment: I will edit my answer in a while but just now I've tested your code and works! No errors. My version: **GNU Awk 4.0.1**

Comment: What version of AWK are you using (`gawk` or otherwise and its version number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented just now, tested it with following script:

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    a["one", "two"] = 1;

    el1 = "one";
    el2 = "two";
    add( el1, el2, a );

    el1 = "one";
    el2 = "three";
    add( el1, el2, a );

    print "length of array: " length( a );
}

function add(element1,element2,array)
{
      if(!(element1 SUBSEP element2 in array))
      {
            printf "Elem1 -> %s\t\tElem2 ->%s\n", element1, element2
            array[element1,element2] = 2;
      }
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk
```

With following output:

```
Elem1 -> one            Elem2 ->three
length of array: 2
```

Comment: I am sorry I did not get the results... The reason behind this is the argument passed to the array is not declared anywhere .. so the function thinks this as a variable and not as an array . I just want to know is there a way to make the function recognize the passing variable as an array and not the variable ..

Comment: I get the error from the `length` function as described at the link you gave, but the OP's code works fine for me in `gawk` 3.1.6. The OP's code is fine for accessing a 2D array using `SUBSEP` and the `in` operator.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Yes. Thank you. I realised later. It confused me the uncommon way of accesing to a multiple subscript array. But checked it later and it's all ok. At least for our versions.